# Active Directory Account Move / No connectivity

Tags: windows, encryption, active-directory, passwords

I have a ONETIME business requirement to move approx. 10,000 AD accounts from various OU's to another domain.  As the move is between a locked down on-premise data center, to an AD in the cloud.  Hence I can't get connectivity between the two domains.  An application is moving out of the DC to the cloud to ease security restrictions, and we are hoping to avoid a mass password change on all the accounts.

I don't have much experience with AD, as I'm more of an application dev guy than a security infrastructure dude - so here goes my perhaps ignorant question.

I've used DSInternals.com to dump the domain using Get-ADReplaccount (Windows Server 2008 R2), and saving the data to a file, but I don't know what to do after this point.

I'm hoping that I can now use this data to import accounts back into a another domain, under a different OU, and "import" them all (including the password hash) into the new domain, on another server.

If Get-ADReplAccount is used to extract, what is the SET cmdlet to use that data?

Comment: Disclaimer up front:  I haven't used the Get-ADReplaccount tool.  What I can tell you is that the number one tool of choice to migrate AD users from one domain to another while _retaining_ their passwords is the ADMT (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19188).  ADMT is a relatively easy-to-use utility, and has a wizard interface to walk you through the accounts you want to migrate.  Since your business customer has accounts in many different OUs, you can migrate accounts over to the cloud domain one OU at a time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can import NTLM hashes into AD using the Set-SamAccountPasswordHash cmdlet from the DSInternals module. Example:

```
Set-SamAccountPasswordHash -SamAccountName john -Domain ADATUM -NTHash 92937945b518814341de3f726500d4ff -Server dc1.adatum.com
```

The hashes can be retrieved either online using Get-ADReplAccount or offline using Get-ADDBAccount from the same module.

Forcing a password change is encouraged though, because such accounts would be missing Kerberos AES keys, so only Kerberos RC4 would be used during authentication of accounts migrated this way.

Comment: why was this answer marked down - please express opinion as to why